# Jest encountered an unexpected token on Testing in React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I am getting error in one of my test case files. I am getting an error for this line:

```
import { ReactComponent as bestSeller } from "../../collection/images/icons/hello.svg";
```

for some reason it's getting error like:

```
● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    C:\*********collections\images\icons\hello.svg:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path class="a" d="M1667.949,842.606,1657,853.559l.048,5,5,.049L1673,847.653Zm3.028,5.047-.478.478-3.028-3.028.478-.478Zm-9.521,9.52-3-.029-.029-3,8.033-8.033,1.01,1.01-7.741,7.74,1.009,1.009,7.741-7.74,1.009,1.009Z" transform="translate(-1656.996 -842.606)"/></svg>
                                                                                             ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

And my Jest configuration in `package.json` looks like:

```
"jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js"
    ]
  },
```

Using "babel-jest": "24.7.1"
and

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.15",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.6.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.4",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1"
  }
```

Comment: *" • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option."*

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you help with an example please

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring)? There's also a specific page on using Jest with Webpack, which is presumably what you're doing: https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack